# Puppeteer behaving differently headless

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have the following script

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function startBrowser() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    return {browser, page};
}

async function closeWindows(page) {
    await page.waitForSelector(selector1);
    await page.click(selector1);
    await page.waitForSelector(selector1);
    await page.click(selector2);
}
async function doStuff(URL) {
    const {browser, page} = await startBrowser();
    await page.goto(URL);
    await closeWindows(page);
}

doStuff(URL)
```

Where `selector1`, `selector2` and `URL` are defined.

This works fine, but as soon as I try to run it in headless mode, I get the following error message:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'waitForSelector' of undefined`. I already tried using

```
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
```

but it just keeps me waiting until I get a TimeoutError. If this helps: the URL is a youtube video.

Comment: @Chris points in his answer, the page is not fully loaded. You should add `waitUntil` in your code and specifically wait for `domcontentloaded`. `load` may not be enough and `networkidel2` may require you to wait too long.

Comment: @AbrarHossain this doesn't work. Again, only headless mode mode presents this issue.

Comment: Are you trying to access the video player? Because that might not even load in headless mode

Comment: Yes, I am, but it was a problem of automatically opening it in mobile mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding the following line:

```
await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');
```

Apparently, the website was being opened in mobile mode.

Comment: It's nice that your problem was solved but that doesn't explain why it would load in mobile mode. That doesn't happen with puppeteer unless you added other code to change the default User Agent

Comment: I didn't change the default User Agent in any way. Also, I'm not the only one with this problem, check out issue #1766 on the official Puppeteer GitHub repository for more information.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. Thanks for the reference

Answer (score 1):

Uhm that seems strange, even if sometimes I myself noticed some discrepancies between the two modes. For example with a customer's website using a React app puppeteer was crashing or something like that.
Instead of using `waitForNavigation`, I'd use the options that `goto` offers you ([see docs here](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.4.1&show=api-pagegotourl-options)).
So it should be something like:

```js
 await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com', { 
     waitUntil: ['load', 'networkidle2'],
     timeout: 10000,
 });
```

This method also returns a [HTTPResponse](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-class-httpresponse) object where you can inspect the status code and the body as text.
Take also a look at the [debugging tips](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#debugging-tips) here, for example intercepting `console` messages and outputting puppeteer's messages from the `DEBUG` module.

Comment: Just setting up my `page.goto` as you suggested doesn't show any immediate improvement, but I will surely make use of the debugging tips, thank you.